# Issues with the size of the shared file mapping object in C++ code

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, shared-memory

I am trying to write into a (shared) named file mapping object like so:

```
//ENTER CRITICAL SECTION FIRST
int ncbSzMapping = 0x92B8;    //Size of a shared struct

hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping((HANDLE)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
    NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 
    0, ncbSzMapping, 
    _T("mapping_name"));
if(hFileMapping)
{
    BYTE* pRWData = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, 
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, ncbSzMapping);
    if(pRWData)
    {
        //Write data into 'pRWData' of 'ncbSzMapping' bytes

        UnmapViewOfFile(pRWData);
    }
}

...
//LEAVE CRITICAL SECTION
```

The code above works without a problem. But when I change the `ncbSzMapping` to `0x8A8B8` the code above succeeds but later down the code I get an exception c00000fd right before a function call that makes no sense to me.

Any idea why that size increase makes a difference and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0xc00000fd is a stack overflow.  Are you declaring a buffer as a local variable with that size?  If so, that's your problem.  Move the buffer off the stack by making it a global or static, or allocate it dynamically using new/delete.

Comment: Are you talking about the `pRWData` in the code? If so, I thought I get an allocated memory pointer to it from `MapViewOfFile`?

Comment: No, I'm talking about buffers you allocate on the stack.  For example, by declaring something like this:  char buffer[0x8a8b8];

Comment: Oh, shoot. You saved me a bunch of time, man. Thanks. I didn't even think about that. Of course! Just from curiosity, what is the stack size?

Comment: The stack size is *something*. You can't rely on it being any particular size, nor should you program with any one specific value in mind. If it ever changes your previously working program could mysteriously break.

Comment: @NikBougalis: You tell me :)

Comment: I'm telling you - the particular size of the stack is irrelevant and you shouldn't rely on it. Even if you knew the amount of stack space is, say, 1MB, there is other stuff consuming stack space below you and calculating how much is left available for your use can be tricky at best. Why do you think that the stack size is important for you to know?

Comment: @NikBougalis: I agreed with you in your first message.